# DAX all active subscriptions in Calendar Month, X number of Months ago

Tags: date, datetime, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am relatively new to DAX and PowerBI, and have an issue that is driving me up the wall.

I have a table with data from my source system and a Calendar table, I also have a Measures table where various DAX Measures are calculated/stored.

In the source System, I have 3 columns that are relevant here: Unique_ID, PurchaseDate, TerminationDate

TerminationDate either has a value (as in the subscription is terminated) or is NULL (and therefore active)

The problem I am trying to solve is that I wish to know how many active subscriptions I had N Number of Months ago and have this as a Dynamic value.

I initially thought I had success with the below bit of code, however when I change the variable Month1 indexing it by increments of 1 eg: =MONTH(TODAY())-2 =MONTH(TODAY())-3 etc.) the value didn't change.

```
Previous 1 month Total active Services = 
var month1= MONTH(TODAY())-1
var year= YEAR(TODAY())
return
calculate(
    COUNTROWS(Table1),
    FILTER(Table1, 
Table1[PurchaseDate] >= month1
    && Table1[PurchaseDate] >= year
    && ((Table1[TerminationDate] <= month1
    && Table1[TerminationDate] <= year) 
    || isblank(Table1[TerminationDate]) )
    ))
```

So, then I decided that the above was trying to be too clever and that I'd simplify things by having a measure for all subscriptions with a purchase date equal or less than todays' Month-1/Year, another measure where the Termination date was less than or equal to todays Month-1/Year and then subtracting one from the other should give the answer.

```
Previous 1 month Total active Services calculation 2 = 
var month1= MONTH(TODAY())-1
var year= YEAR(TODAY())
return
calculate(
    COUNTROWS(Table1),
    FILTER(Table1, 
Table1[TerminationDate] <= month1
    && Table1[TerminationDate] <= year 
    ))
```

Bearing in mind I'm validating the accuracy of the above by running this in the SQL backend (and this is all being done on a copy of the DB, so I know there's no production changes)

```
select count(t.unique_id)
from table1 t
where t.terminationdate <= '2020-07-31'
```

and then doing the same but with '2020-06-30' etc.

Ideally the solution wouldn't necessitate the creation of additional columns nor utilize slicers - this is for (what should be) a very simple calculation.

Sample Data:

> ```
>  Unique_ID          PurchaseDate             TerminationDate
> ```
>
> > ```
> > WM-SP-998407    2016-06-01 07:42:41.000 2020-01-02 11:25:26.000
> > WM-SP-998412    2016-06-01 08:02:11.000 2017-08-30 11:26:31.000
> > WM-SP-998417    2016-06-01 08:11:01.000 2017-08-30 11:26:05.000
> > WM-SP-998422    2016-06-01 08:11:02.000 2017-08-30 11:25:49.000
> > WM-SP-998427    2016-06-01 08:22:41.000 2018-08-30 11:26:18.000
> > WM-SP-998432    2016-06-01 08:47:41.000 NULL
> > WM-SP-998437    2016-06-01 09:22:41.000 2020-03-07 08:10:49.000
> > WM-SP-998442    2016-06-01 09:25:42.000 NULL
> > WM-SP-998447    2016-06-01 09:51:11.000 2018-08-30 11:26:33.000
> > WM-SP-998452    2016-06-01 09:51:11.000 NULL
> > WM-SP-998457    2016-06-01 10:00:51.000 NULL
> > ```

Comment: Best option is just show us some small amount of sample data, then what is requirement and finally what you have tried so far. A long explanation often make things complex to understand.

Comment: Edited with some Sample Data

Comment: Hi @TheDemonLord, is not it the best option for you that - Select a month in Slicer (from list of month) and you get the Active counts for that month?

Comment: There's a reason why we don't want to use a Month Slicer, for something that takes 2-3 lines of code in SQL, I have no idea why datetime manipulation is so unbearably hard in DAX

Comment: Then how you will determine the Month you wants the Count for?